# Need help shortening down function that creates a lot of elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a file with 170 images. These images are displayed on my website and the user can slide to see different pictures. This code works but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do what I did below.

```
var imgCo2 = new Array(); //create new array containing all elements below

    imgCo2[0] = 'co2_model/0.jpg'; //string is this element of the array. string goes to local image located in file co2_model
    imgCo2[1] = 'co2_model/1.jpg';
    imgCo2[2] = 'co2_model/2.jpg';
    imgCo2[3] = 'co2_model/3.jpg';
    imgCo2[4] = 'co2_model/4.jpg';
    imgCo2[5] = 'co2_model/5.jpg';
    imgCo2[6] = 'co2_model/6.jpg';
    imgCo2[7] = 'co2_model/7.jpg';
    imgCo2[8] = 'co2_model/8.jpg';
    imgCo2[9] = 'co2_model/9.jpg';
```

This repeats up to 171 and then I have a similar array with different images that goes to 150. This code is used for a an img slider. The slider code is below.

```
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#imgTemp").prop("src", imageTemp[v]);
});
```

Comment: consider using `Array.prototype.map` or a loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: Instead of explicitly setting each array index, I'd use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 0):

if you image name is not changing did you consider doing something like this

```
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#imgTemp").prop("src", `co2_model/${v}.jpg`);
});
```

in this case you will not need an array at all

Comment: nah my img name changes, names them 0,1,2 etc to make things easier. Was told to go on code review so ill head there thanks.

Comment: one thing I would do is add on the slider image every image as data and then access as $(this).data('image-slider')

Answer (score 0):

Question not closed yet so I'll put the code below. Wasn't as hard as I thought

```
var imgCo2 = new Array();
var i;
for (i= 0; i!=172; i++){ //the 172 is manually put(amount of images in the file starting from 0) 
    imgCo2[i]= 'co2_model/'+i+'.jpg'
}
```